# Manage in Jmeter the Expiration time of a Token

Tags: jmeter

How do I manage in Jmeter, the expiration time of a token, so that it does not affect the continuity of execution of the other requests?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you're getting the token you're getting its [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) as well which could be extracted into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

So you have 2 options:

1. Either periodically send the request for the token refresh in another Thread Group (token TTL minus some reasonable number of seconds), the pause between "refreshes" can be introduced using Constant Timer or Flow Control Action sampler
2. Or make the token refresh a part of the main Thread Group.

   - When you create/refresh the token you can get the current timestamp using [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) and store it into a JMeter Variable
   - Then the current time can be compared to the token refresh timestamp in the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) so you will be able to run the refresh request before the current token expires